# How to introduce logging in a library without adding dependencies?

Tags: .net, logging

I'm working on a library that is supposed to be published as a NuGet package. I would like to expose some diagnostic information, for example when a non-crucial operation fails. If this was a module of application, that is not shared, I would just add a log statement and add a dependency on nLog or log4net. Since this is supposed to be a reusable component, I don't want to have as little dependencies as possible.
What is the preferred way to have diagnostics in a library (NuGet package)?

Comment: One option is to use tracing in combination with a trace switch ('System.Diagnostics.Trace' and 'System.Diagnostics.BooleanSwitch'). See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I had a look at Newtonsoft.Json - they provide an `ITraceWriter` interface with 2 baked in implementation, that write to memory or `System.Diagnostics.TraceListener` @KBO mentioned.

Comment: log4net, as stated above, also contains a ´TraceAppender´ that can be used to forward the trace messages to an output type (file, network etc.) of your choice.